# How to query DynamoDB by string between + other keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to design a DynamoDB query that meets the following criteria:

`get items by type, category, and date between(date_1, date_2)`

I have these attributes already stored in a Global Secondary Index:

- type (string)
- category (string)
- date (string)

I know I could use the `between` operator to query by a given date string:

`gsi_1_pk = 'products' and gsi_1_sk between '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' and '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'`

But there are situations where I want to query by the 3 attributes, not only the date.

So, I want a solution that allows me to query by all the possible filtering combinations: `type`, `category`, `date between`, `type + category`, `type + date between`, `category + date between` `type + category + date between`.

How can I combine this `between` operation with the other attributes from the GSI?

Comment: Will the client always be searching by type or category, or can they search products without specifying either?  Do you need to support a "fetch all products by date" access pattern?

Comment: If you want items where both type and category are known values and date is in a specific range, then create a GSI with pk=type+category and sk=date.

Comment: @jarmod I also need to be able to query by "type + date", or "category + data". Your suggestion would only be a fit if I always needed to use the "type + category". I will add this into the question, thanks.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan yes I need to support the "fetch all by date between" scenario. The clients can search without specifying either.

I have updated the question to include the access patterns I need to cover.

Comment: You can use 3x GSIs for the type/date, category/date, and type+category/date queries.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the type and category fields?  Are they related in any hierarchical way?  How are your Products stored in the main table (PK/SK?).

Comment: Probably an unpopular answer, but maybe DynamoDB isn't the right tool for this job and you should go with an RDS database. You can still do a serverless RDS with Aurora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new Global Secondary Index, where I store the `date` alone at the Sorting Key, which allows me to use the `between` Dynamo operation with no problem.

The downside is that I had to create a new GSI for such a simple query. But as many said here, DynamoDB seems not to be the "right/best" tool for this job.

Comment: I'm curious how that single GSI will support all 7 access patterns you described.